# Core.php in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I used to do some config with "routing.prefix" in cakephp2. It was in the file core.php.
I notice there is no core.php in Cakephp 3. What is the equivalent of core.php in cake 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the core configuration file for cake3 is `config/app.php`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html

but the routes go in the `config/routes.php` file

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

so If you want to have a named routing put it in **routes.php**

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#using-named-routes

Answer (score 0):

that would be the Config/app.php